# tensorflow inception for retraining / fine tuning with a pretrained model: inception_train

Tags: tensorflow, pre-trained-model

I tried to retrain (new images, new classes) on top of the pretrained inception model, I therefor followed the instructions of the inception readme:
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/inception#how-to-construct-a-new-dataset-for-retraining

I successfully built and ran **build_image_data** using *bazel*, as described in the tutorial. Afterwards I successfully built *inception_train* using *bazel*:

```
~/tensorflowmodels/models/inception# bazel build inception/inception_train
INFO: Found 1 target...
Target //inception:inception_train up-to-date (nothing to build)
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.073s, Critical Path: 0.00s
```

However, running bazel-bin/inception/inception_train I always get the following:

```
~/tensorflowmodels/models/inception# bazel-bin/inception/inception_train   --train_dir="/"   --validation_dir="/"   --data_dir="/images_jpg/"   --pretrained_model_checkpoint_path="/tensorflowmodels/models/inception/inception-v3/"   --fine_tune=True   --initial_learning_rate=0.001   --input_queue_memory_factor=1   --num_gpus=1
-bash: bazel-bin/inception/inception_train: No such file or directory
```

Naturally I would say it's by 99.9999% chance a typo. So then I tried to run inception_train.py with python. I had to change some import locations, and it finally ran with the parameters. However the script stops without any error messages after the initialization of the CUDA drivers.

Any help on how to solve this (or perform fine tuning / retraining with inception) would be very much appreciated.

- **tensorflow version**: 0.9rc0
- **CPU**: Xeon 5, 24 cores
- **GPU**: Grid K2 8 GB
- **OS**: Ubuntu 14.04

BTW I posted this already as an Github issue (which was closed, since it would be more a case for Stack Overflow).

Comment: Have you tried putting some prints in the code or using pdb to find out where exactly it stops? These would be my first debugging attempt if I were you.

Comment: I will give it a try, thank you.